# How to view difference between local hijacked file and the server copy of the file in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

Presently I follow this process:

1. Right click the root of the project and click on **Find Modified Files**.
2. Then in the **ClearCase Snapshot View Update** window, the modified (hijacked) files are shown.
3. By right click on the file name and click on **Compare with Old Version**, difference between local hijacked file and the server copy are displayed.

However, the above approach takes very long time (as step 1 itself takes 10 minutes). If I already know the hijacked file path, then is there a faster way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [2007 thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013941795) summarizes the options you have; the command line with cleartool 9.0.1.3 also offers a diff, even though the thread claims that it doesn't. See bottom of the post.

- convert the hijack to checked out (then you can diff)

OR

- rename the hijacked file to something else (like `filename.hijacked`), reload filename (`cleartool update filname`) update the file, then run `cleartool diff filename filename.hijacked`.

OR

- run the diff against the dynamic view version (from command-prompt, cd to the hijacked file location, then do the `cleartool diff filename M:\view\VOB\path\to\file`)

I used to do the third option, as it does not require to touch the hijacked file.

With cleartool, compare an extended path name specifying a version, e.g. /main/LATEST, to an simple path. (A command line can be opened conveniently from the context menu of a folder in ClearCase Explorer.)

```
cleartool diff file.c@@/main/LATEST file.c
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. I am not using dynamic view. So, I guess option1 is best for me. In case of option2, I will need to undo my changes for build (otherwise my changes will not get tested).

Comment: However, I was wondering that **Find Modified Files** gives me the exact functionality that I need (although it is slow). Is it not at all possible to add this option in the right click context menu of the file in **ClearCase Explorer** for hijacked file?

Comment: @lalityadav no, not for hijacked files, unfortunately.

Comment: @lalityadav I meant having a second view, a dynamic view reserved just for this comparison. The fact that you are not using a dynamic view doesn't prevent you to create one with the same config spec for comparing your hijacked files of your current snapshot view with the files (always up-to-date) of the dynamic view. But you are still using your current and usual snapshot view.

Comment: '@VonC Dynamic view always show the latest baseline (Please correct if I am wrong). Thus, if I am working on a different baseline from dynamic view (It can happen if (a) I am working on some old baseline/issue or (b) Somebody has delivered, since my last rebase), then the diff will be between incorrect files. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @lalityadav A dynamic view shows what you tell it to: an UCM dynamic view will show you what an UCM snapshot view would, including the *`LATEST`* version of a branch named after stream. If you are working on a different baseline, you would have *another* dynamic view reflecting that other config spec in order to mirror what your snapshot view  is set to. But if you have many of those snapshot environments, I understand this model doesn't scale easily.

Comment: @lalityadav Late to the party, but the fact that the "modified files" list offered the functionality made me think that there is a cleartool command; and indeed. Right-click the folder to open a command window in that location; then "cleartool diff file@@\main\LATEST file" does the trick.

Comment: @VonC I took the liberty of adding the cleartool option for posterity, including myself in a year. Feel free to roll back if you cannot reproduce or hate cleartool ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thank you for the edit! That is a welcome addition to this answer.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I have more than 300 answers specifically on `cleartool` (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cleartool/topusers), so I really don't "hate" `cleartool` ;)